# TSQL - Query for multiple types in multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where each address has different types, for each type a row. How to find the addresses where for the exact types i need?

Eg.

```
ID  TypID   Street
1   1       Street 1
1   2       Street 1
2   2       Street 2
3   1       Street 3
3   2       Street 3
```

In the above i need to find addresses which has type 1 and 2. That query result should be adresses with id 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the `id` and then count the different `typeid`s in the `having` clause

```
select id from your_table
where typeid in (1,2)
group by id
having count(distinct typeid) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use INTERSECT for this

```
select id
from tbl
where typid = 1
intersect
select id
from tbl
where typid = 2
```

although it won't work in mysql if that happens to be the database you're using.

Comment: @sysboard It does work, as you can see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6abff/1/0 . Perhaps you are not actually using sql server and are using a different database?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a inner join like the below

```
select y2.*
from <your_table> Y1
JOIN <your_table> Y2
ON   Y1.ID = Y2.ID
AND  Y1.Type_id in (1,2)
AND  Y2.ID in (1,3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response. Juergen d has posted before you and his code works for me so i vote yours up.